# How to read data from specific line in a file‎?

Tags: fortran

I have a problem how to read the number from line `n` and column `m` from a text file.

Below is the file. The number I want to read is marked **bold**.

> G07  1437  1437  1437  1437                              PRN / # OF
>   OBS          G08  1437  1437  1437  1437
>   PRN / # OF OBS          G10  1437  1437  1437  1437
>   PRN / # OF OBS          G13  1437  1437  1437  1437
>   PRN / # OF OBS          G15  1437  1437  1437  1437
>   PRN / # OF OBS          G24   809   804   774   774
>   PRN / # OF OBS          G25   816   748   694   694
>   PRN / # OF OBS          G28  1437  1437  1437  1437
>   PRN / # OF OBS       CARRIER PHASE MEASUREMENTS: PHASE SHIFTS REMOVED 
>   COMMENT
>                                                               END OF HEADER         09  6 10 11 50 14.0000000  0  7G07G08G10G13G15G25G28
>
> 21640633.14117    211001.84417    145686.75058  **21640629.92858**
>     20270038.40917     47299.20717     29373.29759  20270035.88059
>     20921122.23717     35179.40617     20913.66459  20921119.72759
>     23375852.17815    245299.13715    159374.10256  23375851.73756
>     24332262.34516    -47567.80516    -24598.05157  24332261.03057
>     23397473.99216    238631.73016    166805.02757  23397473.15457
>     21826760.73217   -130774.53117    -98585.76258  21826757.69358  09  6 10 11 50 15.0000000  0  8G07G08G10G13G15G24G25G28
>     21641196.234 6    213960.266 6    147992.01248  21641193.20548
>     20270164.110 7     **47960.691 7**     29888.74248  20270161.61348
>     20921216.127 7     35674.703 7     21299.61749  20921213.51249
>     23376533.019 6    248872.664 6    162158.66846  23376531.77946
>     24331762.736 6    -50196.488 6    -26646.36747  24331760.98147
>     24599401.84316
>     23398117.377 6    242012.082 6    169439.07047  23398116.40347
>     21826403.256 7   -132653.473 7   -100049.87148  21826400.70948  09  6 10 11 50 16.0000000  0  8G07G08G10G13G15G24G25G28
>     21641758.805 7    216918.813 7    **150297.37548**  21641756.07848
>     20270290.115 7     48622.465 7     30404.41049  20270287.40449
>     20921310.905 7     36170.543 7     21685.98849  20921307.82749
>     23377213.438 6    252446.262 6    164943.27746  23377211.83946
>     24331261.918 6    -52825.297 6    -28694.78547  24331260.53947
>     24599639.441 6
>     23398760.704 6    245392.375 6    172073.07047  23398759.57647
>     21826045.702 7   -134532.152 7   -101513.77748  21826043.03148  09  6 10 11 50 17.0000000  0  8G07G08G10G13G15G24G25G28
>     21642322.125 7    219877.535 7    152602.87548  21642319.08048
>     20270416.177 7     49284.598 7     30920.36349  20270413.70449
>     20921405.154 7     36666.953 7     22072.80148  20921402.13148
>     23377893.321 6    256020.004 6    167728.00846  23377891.84946
>     24330762.414 6    -55454.160 6    -30743.25047  24330760.25447
>     24599877.399 6
>     23399403.485 6    248772.668 6    174707.06647  23399402.65647
>     21825688.338 7   -136410.488 7   -102977.41048  21825685.89248  09  6 10 11 50 18.0000000  0  8G07G08G10G13G15G24G25G28
>     21642885.530 7    222836.375 7    154908.46548  21642882.14548
>     20270542.254 7     49947.043 7     31436.54749  20270539.58049
>     20921499.789 7     37163.945 7     22460.07048  20921496.78948
>     23378573.557 6    259593.785 6    170512.77746  23378571.94746
>     24330261.660 6    -58083.102 6    -32791.77747  24330259.94247
>     24600114.981 6
>     23400047.052 6    252152.898 6    177341.01247  23400046.00147
>     21825331.225 7   -138288.496 7   -104440.78948  21825328.12748  09  6 10 11 50 19.0000000  0  8G07G08G10G13G15G24G25G28
>     21643448.790 7    225795.313 7    157214.13348  21643445.39848
>     20270668.553 7     50609.801 7     31952.98049  20270666.09149
>     20921594.496 7     37661.504 7     22847.77348  20921591.58548
>     23379252.757 5    263167.641 5    173297.60946  23379252.06246
>     24329761.100 6    -60712.121 6    -34840.36747  24329759.15547
>     24600353.301 6
>     23400690.655 6    255533.066 6    179974.90647  23400689.68747
>     21824974.083 7   -140166.188 7   -105903.92248  21824970.73848

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that shows techniques to skip lines and numbers to reach the item that you want.   You might have to switch to formatted reads if the column alignment is more important the the count of numbers.

```
program test

integer, parameter :: DBL_K = selected_real_kind (14)

character (len=132) :: skip
integer :: i, j
real (DBL_K) :: junk (100), good (100)

open (file="test.txt", unit=25, form="formatted", access="sequential", status="old", action="read")

do i=1, 11
   read (25, '(A)' )  skip
end do

read (25, *) (junk (j), j=1,3), good (1)


write (*, *) good (1)

end program test
```